# How to maintain websocket connection if I have multiple version of node in one in application

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have many modules in my application and few modules use latest node version and some old version of node. Every time the user switches between the old and the new module, A new socket connection has to be established and the old connection is terminated. This is unstable. Is there a better way to handle it ?

Comment: What modules are you using that require an old version of node? You should probably not be using them if that's the case.

Comment: Its actually a huge application and its difficult to migrate quickly. Ideally I shouldn't be using old version of node but no choice right now.

Comment: So you have two versions of node running concurrently?

Comment: Not concurrently. A part of the application consumes separate node modules and the same goes for the old version node. You can't run concurrently two versions.